# bash grep only numbers and compare them

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

`Index.html` of the curl command looks like below.

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of myorg/release/builds/production/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of myorg/release/builds/production/</h1>
<pre>Name                                        Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="1.0.60/">1.0.60/</a>                                      06-Jul-2022 07:47    -
<a href="1.0.63/">1.0.63/</a>                                      06-Jul-2022 10:21    -
<a href="1.0.64/">1.0.64/</a>                                      09-Jul-2022 18:08    -
<a href="1.0.65/">1.0.65/</a>                                      09-Jul-2022 18:42    -
<a href="1.0.71/">1.0.71/</a>                                      10-Jul-2022 10:23    -
<a href="1.0.73/">1.0.73/</a>                                      14-Jul-2022 17:28    -
<a href="1.0.75/">1.0.75/</a>                                      20-Jul-2022 07:25    -
<a href="%f%7D/">{STOCKIO}/</a>                                 24-May-2022 11:09    -
<a href="dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz">dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz</a>          24-May-2022 07:27  87.74 MB
<a href="dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.md5">dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.md5</a>      24-May-2022 07:27  32 bytes
<a href="dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.sha1">dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.sha1</a>     24-May-2022 07:27  40 bytes
<a href="dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.sha256">dashboard-react-module-1.0.29.tar.gz.sha256</a>   24-May-2022 07:27  64 bytes
<a href="dashboard-react-module.tar.gz">dashboard-react-module.tar.gz</a>                 24-May-2022 07:27  87.74 MB
<a href="dashboard-react-module.tar.gz.md5">dashboard-react-module.tar.gz.md5</a>             24-May-2022 07:27  32 bytes
<a href="dashboard-react-module.tar.gz.sha1">dashboard-react-module.tar.gz.sha1</a>            24-May-2022 07:27  40 bytes
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/6.23.41 Server .myorg.com Port 80</address></body></html>
```

I'm unable to construct a logic to find the largest entry in the file, here its - `1.0.75`

I tried grepping only the numbers like -  `grep -E "[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]{1,4}" index.html` but it throws the same output as above.

My idea is to get all the numeric entries like `1.0.60, 1.0.63 ...` in to an array, cut the last part of the number and compare them to get the largest number, but, unable to find the right `grep` command that gives only the numeric values.

Or is there a much efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Further below in the address tag is the entry `6.23.41`, which is even larger. If you want to exclude this, you need first to specify exactly how the candidate lines for the entry can look like.

Comment: Your `grep` command outputs all lines which have in them a text matching your pattern. If you **only** need the pattern, not the whole line, you have to specify the `-o` option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` to filter the data, `sort` to arrange (in case unsorted) and `tail` to show the last (largest) entry

```
$ sed -En '/href/s~[^>]*>([0-9][^/]*).*~\1~p' input_file | sort -n | tail -1
1.0.75
```

- Match lines containing the string `href`
- Capture within parenthesis the match and exclude everthing else
- Return the match with backrefence `\1`
- sort the piped output by numbers
- Print the last line (highest value)

Comment: perfect, thanks..
Can you kindly explain a bit though :) that would be really helpful.

Comment: @ChelMS Please check edit

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following GNU `awk`+ `sort` with `head` solution.

```
awk 'match($0,/<a href="([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)/,arr){print arr[1] | "sort -rV | head -1"}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk` program to parse Input_file to it. Where using its `match` function in which using regex `<a href="([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/)` where it creates capturing group of matched values to only have versions in it. GNU `awk` capabilities to store matched regex values as values into array so creating `arr` array which will contain only version values. Then using `|` to run BASH command `sort -rV`(Version sort) to get it revers order sort(descending order) and once all values ae printed; sending this output to `head` command and printing only very first output which will be highest version only.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and input :)

Answer (score 1):

No doubt a lot of ways to do this..

```
cat foo1.x | grep 'href="[0-9]' | sed -E 's/.*href=.1.0.([0-9]+).*/\1/' | sort -u -n | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Versions are sorted in index.html..

Getting the last one

```
awk -F'["/]' '/href="([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\/"/{n=$2}END{print n}' index.html

1.0.75
```

If versions are not sorted

```
 awk -F'["/]' '
   /href="([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\/"/ { a[NR]=$2 } 
   END{
       asorti(a,b,"@val_num_desc");
       print a[b[1]]
   }
' index.html

1.0.75
```